# Java synchronized блокирует класс а не объект?

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency, synchronized

Добрый день, недавно читал Брюса Эккеля, и наткнулся на такую проблему: блок synchronized(Object) блокирует класс обьекта, е не сам обьект. К такому выводу я пришел после выполнения такого кода :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sync s = new Sync();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                s.go();
            }
        }, "First").start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                s.go();
            }
        }, "Second").start();
    }
}

class Sync {

    private Writer w1, w2;

    public Sync() {
        w1 = new Writer();
        w2 = new Writer();
    }

    public void go() {
        synchronized (w2) {
            w1.log(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "...1");
            //!Этот блок кода должен выполнятся паралельно во всех потоках, но выполняется последовательно.
            w2.log(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "...2");
            //Этот должен выполнятся последовательно, и он так и делает.
        }
    }
}

class Writer {
    public void log(Object obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            lgn(obj);
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(750);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Почему при блокировки w2, у меня блокируется и w1? Это же разные обьекты?

В книге и во всех источниках говорится про блокировку в synchronized обьекта! Если я что-то не так сделал или чего-то не понимаю, то могли бы вы мне ответить почему и как?

Вывод

```
First...1
First...1
First...1
First...1
First...1
First...2
First...2
First...2
First...2
First...2
Second...1
Second...1
Second...1
Second...1
Second...1
Second...2
Second...2
Second...2
Second...2
Second...2
```

Ожидаемый вывод

```
First...1
Second...1
First...1
Second...1
First...1
Second...1
First...1
Second...1
First...1
Second...1
First...2
First...2
First...2
First...2
First...2
Second...2
Second...2
Second...2
Second...2
Second...2
```

Comment: Синхронизация происходит по объекту, указанному в synchronized, а у вас это всегда w2, поэтому w1 всегда курит бамбук и вам кажется , что синхронизация происходит по классу

Comment: А можно детальней, я просто не понял как независимый обьект w2 при свой синхронизации может повлиять на синхронизацию w1?

Comment: Давайте с другой стороны... Попробуйте заменить метод так     public synchronized void go() {
            w1.log(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "...1");
            System.out.println("*");
            //!Этот блок кода должен выполнятся паралельно во всех потоках, но выполняется последовательно.
            w2.log(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "...2");
            System.out.println("**");
            //Этот должен выполнятся последовательно, и он так и делает.
        }

Comment: Посмотрите , как он выполняется, может прояснит ситуацию...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваши комментарии в коде:

```
synchronized (w2) {
    w1.log(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "...1");
    //!Этот блок кода должен выполнятся паралельно во всех потоках, но выполняется последовательно.
    w2.log(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "...2");
    //Этот должен выполнятся последовательно, и он так и делает.
}
```

неверны.

Секция `synchronized` синхронизирует не *объект*, а *участок кода*. Это означает, что вся секция будет выполнена «одним куском», не прерываясь другой секцией с тем же синхронизирующим объектом (это как раз ваш случай).

Таким образом, сначала код в потоке `"First"` приходит к синхронизирующей секции и **выполняет её полностью**, и только потом поток `"Second"`. (Ну или в обратном порядке, как повезёт.)

Comment: ОК, допустим я понял, но если по этому блоку кода будет пробигатся только один поток, то зачем нам надо еще что-то кидать в параметры? (скобки)

Comment: @NikitaGordia: Ну, секции, которые синхронизируются по разным объектам, независимы. Иначе если у вас один кусок кода синхронизируется, то его будут ждать _все_ другие синхронизирующиеся куски во всей программе, даже если это вам и не нужно.